# Programmatically bind property to GridViewColumn.Width

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, properties

I got a WPF MVVM application containing a ListView containing a GridView.
Using a helper class I'm creating the GridViewColumn's, which works nicely.

My problem: I want to twoway-bind the width so I can read back changes to the width.

The code to create the GridViewColumn right now looks like this:

```
private static GridViewColumn CreateColumn(GridView gridView, object columnSource)
{
  GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
  String headerTextMember = GetHeaderTextMember(gridView);
  String displayMemberMember = GetDisplayMemberMember(gridView);
  String widthMember = GetWidthMember(gridView);
  // set header
  column.Header = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, headerTextMember);

  // set display binding
  String propertyName = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, displayMemberMember) as String;
  column.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(propertyName);

  // bind with - but how?
  //Binding widthBinding = new Binding(widthMember);
  //widthBinding.Source = columnSource;
  //widthBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
  //gridView.SetBinding(GridViewColumn.WidthProperty, widthBinding); <- gridView got no SetBinding :(
  }
  return column;
}
```

Anyone got some pointers for me how I might be able to bind the width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out: [BindingOperations.SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx)

> This method creates a new instance of
>   a BindingExpressionBase and associates
>   the instance with the given dependency
>   property of the given object. This
>   method is the way to attach a binding
>   to an arbitrary DependencyObject that
>   may not expose its own SetBinding
>   method.

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(column, GridViewColumn.WidthProperty, widthBinding);
```

Comment: the GridView does not contain the method SetBinding, where do I have to look for this?

Comment: @Sam: Yes! Since the GridViewColumn class (not GridView) doesn't have the SetBinding method, the binding has to be done this way. Check my edit for code.

Comment: Oh, BindingOperations is a static class - I always was looking for some class derived from BindingOperations.
Thanks!!